# classes and strings in definitions in python

Tags: python, class, function

```
class someDistance(Distance):
 def __init__(self, dist_funct_name_str = 'Something Distance', p=2):
  self.p = p
```

Just wanted to ask what the

```
dist_funct_name_str = 'Something Distance'
```

does in the definition?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is used to define the default value of the variable `dist_funct_name_str`in case when no value is passed for it when the object `someDistance` was invoked.

example:

```
In [69]: def func(a,b=2): # b has default value of 2
   ....:     print a,b
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [70]: func(1)   # no value passed for b ,so it is equal to 2
1 2

In [71]: func(1,5) # 5 is passed for b, so b=2 is neglected
1 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `dist_funct_name_str` and `p` are called default values.  If these values aren't set when `__init__` is called, then these default values are used instead.

They also occur on other functions as well - not just `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dist_funct_name_str = 'Something Distance'
```

Is a "default parameter" passed to the init function. It's basically the parameter used by default of a user or coder has not passed any arguments to a function.

You can read up a bit more on this here: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm and I also recommend this: http://www.deadlybloodyserious.com/2008/05/default-argument-blunders/ .

I've run into the same thing not long ago.